# Bash CD commands outputting environment variables

Tags: ruby, bash, windows-10, environment-variables

[image]

I was trying to install ruby and makeFile along with rvm in windows but after their installation bash cd commands is outputting wired things on console.

I have uninstalled ruby and rest of the software but the issue still persist.

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Comment: I will ensure from next time to post question in proper format.
@RenaudPacalet

Answer (score -1):

I deleted .rvm and .uru folder in c>Users>UserName and now the bash is working as expected.